# Angular ngx-translate nested translate in en.json?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I would like to translate a statement inside of an html template. The translated statement itself contains a translate pipe. This does not seem to be working is there an alternative approach?

in the HTML:

```
<div class="description">
        {{ state + "-page.intro-info-description" | translate }}

        <ul class="bullet">
        <li>{{ state + "-page.intro-info-1" | translate }}</li>
        <li>{{ state + "-page.intro-info-2" | translate }}</li>
        <li>{{ state + "-page.intro-info-3" | translate }}</li>
        </ul>

    {{ "intro-info-description" | translate }}

    </div>
```

en.json:

```
{
 "intro-info-description": "You can register with 
 {{ 'provider' | translate }} if you can provide the following 
 information:",

"provider:": "Provider"
}
```

I would like the page to say : 
"You can register with Provider if you can provide the following 
     information:"

Instead it says:

"You can register with 
     {{ 'provider' | translate }} if you can provide the following 
     information:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translateParam for this.

the Html looks like this:

```
{{ state + "-page.intro-info-description" | translate: { provider: (state + "-page.provider" | translate) } }}
```

or as a element

```
<p [translate]="state + '-page.intro-info-description'" [translateParams]="{ provider: (state + "-page.provider" | translate)}"></p>
```

your json files will look this:

```
{
 "intro-info-description": "You can register with 
 {{provider}} if you can provide the following 
 information:",

"provider:": "Provider"
}
```